How to install previous version of jhipster-entity-audit?
We already have an existing JHipster application that was created on 8.1.0 version.
Currently, we have no near plan of upgrading it to the latest version.
We want to use the already installed jhipster-entity-audit v5.4.0 (generator-jhipster 8.5.0) for the existing JHipster app of v8.1.0. But it's restricting us from upgrading the existing JHipster application to the latest version and then user entity-audit on top of it.
We observed that to use jhipster-entity-audit on JHipster project, the versions of generator-jhipster and JHipster must be the same.
Is there a way to downgrade or install a specific version of jhipster-entity-audit to serve our purpose?
